# How to create “wss://...” Websocket using PHP and connect to it using JS?

Tags: javascript, php, ssl, websocket

I want to create a chat room using PHP's Websocket. My website has SSL certificate and it's not signed by myself. So I can browse my website in https://... successfully.

But there's a problem that I don't know how to create “wss://...” Websocket using PHP and connect it using JS. Below is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$port = XXX;
$socket = stream_socket_server("wss://mysite.com:".$port, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$socket) {
  echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
  while ($conn = stream_socket_accept($socket)) {
    fwrite($conn, 'some data...\n');
    fclose($conn);
  }
  fclose($socket);
}
?>
```

I don't know what the `$port` should be. Also, I don't know whether the code above is correct way to create “wss://...” Websocket or not.

And below is the JS code:

```
var mySocket = new WebSocket("wss://mysite.com:XXX");
mySocket.send("Hello world!");
mySocket.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
}
mySocket.close();
```

And the console always shows error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://mysite.com:XXX/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I'm the beginner of Websocket. Could someone help me to connect to “wss://...” Websocket?

Comment: I spent several weeks coding up a working PHP websocket class - and it did eventually work with standard and ssl connections but it was flaky and there were issues. Eventually I opted for Node.js and after a few days of trial and error had a fully working websocket chat system going - my advice, go for node,js

Comment: There are all sorts of stages that you need to go through to create a wss connection, all of them fairly complicated but you can find various pre-rolled php scripts on github